# Multiple Product category Select for custom WooCommerce plugin setting page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, multi-select

I am creating a little plugin and have troubles to find out how to create multiple category selection in my settings page. I am using multiple product selection like this which saves the selected values into options table:

```
<select class="wc-product-search" multiple="multiple" style="width: 50%;" id="namedayemail_options[exclude_prods]" name="namedayemail_options[exclude_prods][]" data-placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search for a product&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" data-action="woocommerce_json_search_products_and_variations" >
    <?php
    if (isset($options['exclude_prods'])) {
        $ex_product_ids = $options['exclude_prods'];
        foreach ( $ex_product_ids as $product_id ) {
            $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
            if ( is_object( $product ) ) {
                echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $product_id ) . '"' . selected( true, true, false ) . '>' . wp_kses_post( $product->get_formatted_name() ) . '</option>';
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

I am looking for similar solution for product categories.

*I am sure LoicTheAztec will know the solution. Thanks ahead.* :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get inspirations from [Admin coupon edit page](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.1/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/meta-boxes/class-wc-meta-box-coupon-data.php#L246-L258) code:

```
<p class="form-field">
    <label for="namedayemail_options[exclude_cats]"><?php _e( 'Exclude categories', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
    <select id="namedayemail_options[exclude_cats]" name="namedayemail_options[exclude_cats][]" style="width: 50%;"  class="wc-enhanced-select" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'No categories', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
    <?php
    $category_ids = $options['exclude_cats'];
    $categories   = get_terms( 'product_cat', 'orderby=name&hide_empty=0' );
    if ( $categories ) {
        foreach ( $categories as $cat ) {
            echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $cat->term_id ) . '"' . wc_selected( $cat->term_id, $category_ids ) . '>' . esc_html( $cat->name ) . '</option>';
        }
    }
    ?>
    </select>
</p>
```

Maybe some adjustements will be required…

Comment: As always, you are the best!! It works like a charm.